# How to validate TextBox value is string in C# Windows Form application

Tags: c#

I'm using a TextBox to enter user's name, here I want to **validate that box only having alphabets** which is starting with capital and continues with simple letters. For that I use the following code, even though its validating but if I enter a number after some alphabates it is not identifying that, please some one help me to find the problem.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox3.Text, @"[a-zA-Z]"))
{
    errorProvider2.SetError(textBox3, "Only use alphabates");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. Satisfies all your conditions:

```
@"^[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+$"
```

---

`[A-Z]{1}`- Matches the first letter to uppercase and only once.
`[a-z]+`  - Matches only lower case letters one or more times
`$` -       Marks the end of string, so numbers aren't matched any more

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox3.Text, @"[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s\'-]*")) 
    { 
        errorProvider2.SetError(textBox3, "Only use alphabates"); 
    }
```

Comment: @user1724557 this will accept space, single quote, and negative sign.

Comment: Here text box is used for User names, so there may be space,hyphen  between names.

Comment: but is hyphen and single quote a letter? or space part of the alphabet?

Answer (score 2):

use this pattern

^[A-Z]?[a-z]*$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input = textBox3.Text;
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Comment: Doesn't satisfy first letter to be a capital letter, it will accept lowercase also

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, It might help you.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(textBox3.Text, @"^[A-Z][A-Za-z]*$"))
{
    errorProvider2.SetError(textBox3, "Only use alphabets");
}
```

It starts with capital letters and be followed by zero or more letters of any case.

Comment: This will fail when it is something like **eEE** and it still accepts